# MySQL Query variation for WHERE IN statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a query equivalent to something like

```
WHERE some_field IN (1, 2, !3, !4)
```

meaning

```
WHERE some_field = 1 AND some_field = 2 AND some_field != 3 AND some_field != 4
```

?

Comment: how can some_field have two different values at once? IN translates to OR's not AND's

Comment: What you want must be `OR` not `AND`, Please recheck.

Comment: I think the answer is no because it's meaningless to have 1 and not 3 in same group.

Comment: Yes.  `WHERE some_field is not null`.  Every value is either not equal to 3 or not equal to 4.  Please provide sample data to explain the logic you are looking for.

Comment: the records can have some other common field. so there could be 5 records with the same field_1, but can have different field_2. and my query would search all the records with the same field_1's WHERE field_2 in (1, 2, !3, !4). does that make any sense?

Answer (score -2):

You should have one of the following `where` conditions as both together doesn't make sense:-

```
  WHERE some_field IN (1, 2)
```

or

```
  WHERE some_field NOT IN (3, 4)
```

Comment: This will do nothing different than WHERE some_field IN (1, 2)

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: I have put a `OR` condition between them, not `and`, so both conditions have a role, I think thats what questioner has intended.

Comment: I'm not sure this works either.  The second statement makes the first superfluous

Answer (score -2):

This depends a lot on context.

```
 Where some_field IN (1, 2)
```

already will not return records where some_field equals 3 or 4.

The likely situation is that you have a table with many versions of some_field associated with the same ID, and you want to only return those with 1 and 2 some_fields, but if they also have a 3 or 4 in the table, you want to exclude them.  Then you would want to do something like:

```
 Select * from table
 WHERE some_field = 1
 AND some_ID in (select some_ID from table
            where some_field = 2)
 AND some_ID Not IN (select some_ID from table
                where some_field IN (3, 4))
```

Which will exclude all the ids with a some_field value of 3 or 4 from the list of results with a some_field of 1 and 2

Comment: How come you put `ID IN` and `ID NOT IN` in where conditions??

Comment: I'm assuming the table has a primary key.  You could also use exists and not exists, but I prefer IN and NOT IN